# Delphi Factory with generic Type

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a generic type which is shown below and want to create a factory to product an IItem by creating a descendant of TItem. Further would like to register the factory with the Parent TItem so that it can spawn multiple children objects of the type registered with the factory. I have seen this done with factories registered in a TDictionary but never with a parameterised type.

```
Type
  IItem<T> = interface (IInterface)
    Function GetParent:IItem<T>;
    Procedure SetParent(aItem:IItem<T>);
    property Parent:IItem<T> read GetParent write SetParent;
  end;

  TItem<T> = class(TInterfacedObject,IItem<T>)
  private
    FParent : IItem<T>;
    FData : T;
    Function GetParent:IItem<T>;
    Procedure SetParent(aItem:IItem<T>);
  public
    property Parent:IItem<T> read GetParent write SetParent;
    Constructor Create(aParent:IItem<T>);
  end;
```

I would like to use a TItemFactory that creates an IITem implementing a descendant of TITem by passing in the class to a constructor. This factory will be called from within TItem so T will only be known when TITem is instantiated with a concrete data type. I have attempted to create this factory class but the compiler rejects my attempts to use the generic type. My question is how can I create the TItemFactory class and be able to pass in a class to be created.

My thoughts for this were:

```
  TItemClass = class of TItem<T>;

  TItemFactory<T>= class (TObject)
    Function getItem:IItem<T>;
    constructor Create(AClass:TItemClass);
  end;
```

However this does not compile so I must be on the wrong track.

Comment: Very difficult to know what you are asking. For sure you can write this code. May or may not be useful. What is your question?

Comment: @David I have edited the question to be more specific about what I am trying to do here, hope that makes sense

Comment: I still cannot understand this.  I cannot see any factory.  Your interface is not good because all instantiations have the same GUID.

Comment: Ok, removed the GUID off the interface and put up what I had been thinking for the factory.

Comment: Instead of passing the item class to the factory, pass `TFunc<IItem<T>>`